# 0 to 2 VDC to 4-20 mA using OP07

Tags: simulation, multisim, simulink

I am trying to build a curcuit to convert 0 - 2  VDC to 4-20mA using two OP07.. I have designed the circuit in multisim as in the attached file. I have also developed the circuit on the general purpose pcb. In physical circuit at 0 VDC it gives me some milli Amps out put which i can adjust to 4 mA using 1k trim port. In multisim the output at 0 volts is stuck at 6.086mA it doesn't change even though i change 1k trim port value. Any idea where i am going wrong. I have chosen to simulate circuit because this is my trial and error process, so to save time i have switched on to multisim simulator. At 2 VDC the output changes and that i can trim to 20mA using  **R8** 1k trim port. I am able to adjust the span output but fail to adjust the zero output.

Any idea what i am doing wrong.

Is it possible to simulate this circuit in simulink ?

[image]

In my physical circuit it gives me output from 4-20mA but in between the output is not linear, so i need to play with the values of resistors and this is the reason i wanted to simulate the circuit and fine tune if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Before simulating, which is really just a virtual version of building it and b*ggering around with it on the bench, you should **design** the circuit to do what you want.

One thing that leaps out from a glance at your schematic is that you are not respecting the input common mode range of the OP-07. It is only guaranteed to work to within 2V (1V typically) of the positive supply and you are at 1V with a 4mA output. You can solve this by adding a couple of series diodes between the 12V supply and the R11/R14 junction. That will reduce the output compliance range by two diode drops, of course.

Nonlinearity (severe nonlinearity anyway) is a red flag that indicates something is saturating or is going out of range. You will also see nonlinearity if  your load resistance is too high (but in your case you have it almost shorted). You will want to test it from near zero to something like 200 ohms.

This is not the sort of thing that simulation can always find because the **model** will not typically represent worst-case characteristics, more likely "typical" or sometimes better than typical. This can lead to the unfortunate situation where the simulation works perfectly, the prototype works on the bench, and when you order 1,000 made at the factory 20% of them fail the final test, and a fraction of the remainder are marginal, perhaps at temperature extremes.

Normally on 4-20mA transmitter circuits we would like to have overrange capability from perhaps 3.6mA to maybe 22+mA in order to indicate situations such as a broken sensor or loss of power.

For simulation I would recommend [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice), which is a free download, rather than MATLAB simulation.